# Commit gets associated with two tags instead of one. Why?

Tags: git, github

I am starting a Git repository with 2 commits and each one should be associated with one tag.

The first commit adds only 3 files (tag v0.0.0) and the second commit adds remaining files (tag v0.1.0):

```
git init
git add .gitignore LICENCE README.md 
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git tag -a v0.0.0 -m "Version 0.0.0"
git add .
git commit -m "Add initial source"
git tag -a v0.1.0 -m "Version 0.1.0"
git branch -m main
git remote add origin https://github.com/...
git push -u origin main --tags
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

When I run it and check Github the first commit is associated with both tags.

Why?

**Update 1**

The result from `git log --graph --oneline --all`:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in Source/.git/
[main (root-commit) 1bf2218] Initial commit
 4 files changed, 59 insertions(+)
 create mode 100755 .gitignore
 create mode 100755 LICENCE
 create mode 100755 README.md
[main 4e08a23] Add initial source
 62 files changed, 3635 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .github/workflows/main.yml
 create mode 100755 HISTORY.md
 create mode 100644 gitversion.yml
 create mode 100755 nuget.config
 ...
Enumerating objects: 79, done.
Counting objects: 100% (79/79), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
Writing objects: 100% (79/79), 29.20 KiB | 1.82 MiB/s, done.
Total 79 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), done.
To https://github.com/...
 * [new branch]      main -> main
 * [new tag]         v0.0.0 -> v0.0.0
 * [new tag]         v0.1.0 -> v0.1.0
branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
* 4e08a23 (HEAD -> main, tag: v0.1.0, origin/main) Add initial source
* 1bf2218 (tag: v0.0.0) Initial commit
```

**Update 2**

After running the previous code I get two commits with Ids:

```
Initial commit > 1bf2218
Add initial source > 4e08a23
```

I then ran the following code:

```
> git tag --contains 1bf2218
  v0.0.0
  v0.1.0

> git tag --contains 4e08a23
  v0.1.0
```

It seems the "Initial Commit" gets associated with both tags.

Maybe my interpretation of what's going on is wrong?

What is shows in Tag and Commit pages in Github is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the evidence, the command results. What did the second commit say? What did the push say? Also: `git log --graph --oneline --all` results. edit: that was not my downvote, but it was a near thing. You've got the time in here to know better.

Comment: I just added the log result. Does this help? I have been trying many options and in Github always shows two tags in Ìnitial Commit`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "check GitHub" but in what _you_ have shown there is one tag on "Initial commit" and one tag on "Add initial source", which you claim is what you want. What's the problem exactly? We are looking right at your repo, as described by `git log`, and it is _not_ true that any commit is "associated with two tags instead of one".

Comment: It's showing you pushed tags to two different commits, and github accepted them. Only things I can think of are (this first one seems unlikely but hey, I've blindspotted harder) what you're seeing on github is not the repo you think it is, or maybe github isn't invalidating cached results with the tag names, and if shift-F5 or wait a few minutes it'll show up, or you should be talking to github support.

Comment: _"When I run it and check Github the first commit is associated with both tags"_ How are you checking which commit a tag is associated with? Are you perhaps clicking on the commit ID in GitHub, and then noticing that both tags are listed in the banner at a the top? If so, do note that GitHub lists every reference that contains the commit in its history on the commit's page. If you want to see which commit a tag is associated with, navigate to the tag's page and see which commit ID is listed there. Alternatively, take a look at Insights > Network and see which commits the tag labels are on.

Comment: For example, if you look at the [tag page for CPython v3.13.0a1](https://github.com/python/cpython/releases/tag/v3.13.0a1), you can see that its associated with the commit `ad056f0`. But if you look at [the page for `ad056f0`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ad056f03aee8000a1564a1d17f655f8713c48e48), you'll see every v3.13 tag listed in the top banner (since all those tags contain `ad056f0` in their histories)

Comment: @Brian61354270 So maybe the problem is my interpretation of it? I am not sure as when I run "git tag --contains 1bf2218" I get two tags. Shouldn't be only one?

Comment: @Brian61354270 I just added a new update with a few more checks and Github Tags and Commits pages prints. Does this help to help figuring this out?

Comment: @jthill I added a new update with more checks and Github Tags and Commits pages prints. Does this help?

Comment: `git tag --contains` lists all the tags that *contain* the commit anywhere in their tree. Not the tags that were created exactly at that commit. Both tags contain the initial commit so `git tag --contains` lists both of them.

Comment: If you want tags that are associated with a specific commit, use `git tag --points-at` instead.

Comment: @GuyIncognito By using `git tag --points-at` I get only one tag per commit ... So I suppose it is correct. I just don't understand why the phrase "all the tags that contains the commit anywhere in their tree" and how it relates to what I am getting when running my code.

Comment: Simplified, the tree is the tagged commit and all the previous commits leading up to it in this branch. The initial commit is in both tags because it's the tagged commit in v0.0.0 and the previous commit of v0.1.0. The second commit is only in v0.1.0 because it's not a previous commit of v0.0.0 (but a future one.)

Comment: MiguelMoura it does help. @Brian61354270 nailed it, when you look at a commit GitHub shows you all tags that include that commit. Wanting to know what tags include a commit is very common, it makes sense that GitHub would show you this. When you look at a tag, GitHub shows you want commit it points directly at.

Comment: @MiguelMoura In git's terminology, a tag "contains" a particular commit if that commit appears anywhere in the history of the commit that the tag points to. A tag can only point to one commit, but can contain any number of commits in its associated history. There's a few different git commands that use a `--contains` option in this way. A particular common one is `git-branch`, which mentions in its docs: _"With `--contains`, shows only the branches that contain the named commit (in other words, the branches whose tip commits are descendants of the named commit)"_

Comment: @GuyIncognito Just to avoid any confusion, the term tree has a [particular meaning in git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#_tree_objects), which is different from how its being used here. The tree of a commit is the top level directory / filesystem snapshot that the commit is associated with. E.g. you can see which tree a commit is associated with by running `git cat-file commit <id>`, and view the contents of the tree with `git ls-tree <id>`. The git docs use the terms "history", "ancestry chain", or just chain to refer to all the commits reachable from a given commit